# Como funciona o Math.sqrt no javascript?

Tags: javascript, matemática

Tudo bem, sei que ele retorna a raiz quadrada de um número. Mas, que operações numéricas ele faz pra trazer esse resultado?

Comment: Não sei exatamente como o Javascript faz, mas há muitas formas. Uma das mais "famosas" é o [*Babylonian Method*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method) em que o valor da raíz (inicialmente chutado a partir do número de dígitos do valor para o qual se quer extrair a raíz) é "ajustado" pela média de valores super e sobre-estimados até convergir (isto é, não mais se alterar - veja o exemplo na página da Wikipedia referenciada).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Como eu [já havia comentado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71974/como-funciona-o-math-sqrt-no-javascript#comment147497_71974), eu não sei exatamente como o Javascript faz. Segundo [a resposta do colega @Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/71985/73), os navegadores têm liberdade de implementar nativamente como mais bem entenderem (e provavelmente usam também as implementações nativas das linguagens que foram utilizadas para criá-los).

De todas as formas, uma das implementações mais simples decorre do método de Newton (ainda que tenha sido descoberta ao menos 16 séculos antes - [mais detalhes na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method)). Ela se chama Método Babilônico (*Babylonian Method*).

A ideia é simples. Calcular [image: raíz quadrada de S] é o mesmo que resolver a equação: [image: equação similar], já que o valor de [image: x] encontrado será igual à raíz quadrada procurada.

Em grosso modo, a resolução pelo [método de Newton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) consiste em melhorar iterativamente o valor da raíz* da função estimada subtraindo dela uma "taxa de erro" ainda existente.

<sub>*Isto é, o valor de `x` que faz a função resultar em `0` - não confundir com o valor da "raíz" quadrada.</sub>

A taxa de erro é dada pela razão entre o valor retornado pela função e o valor retornado pela primeira derivada da função:

[image: taxa de erro]

Dessa forma, ao subtrair essa taxa de erro de um valor inicial escolhido [image: x0], obtém-se um novo valor [image: x1] mais próximo do valor real desejado:

[image: novo valor]

Essa operação pode ser repetida (subtraindo-se o erro do novo valor) até que se obtenha um valor suficientemente próximo do real (convergência). A animação abaixo, reproduzida do link da Wikipedia sobre o método, ilustra esse processo iterativo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A linha vermelha, tangente na curva no ponto de interseção do valor de `x` escolhido no momento, é a derivada da função naquele ponto. Ela corta o eixo `x` em outro ponto, obtido pela subtração. Assim, observa-se como gradualmente os novos valores convergem para o ponto de interesse (a raíz da função, isto é, o valor de `x` onde a curva corta o eixo `x` dado que deseja-se igualar a função a `0`).

Como a função de interesse é [image: equação similar] (onde a raíz da função será igual a raíz quadrada de `S`), ela pode ser algebricamente trabalhada como está descrito na Wikipedia (no primeiro link referenciado, sobre métodos de estimação):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, basta processar iterativamente o valor...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

... até a convergência, ou seja, até que a próxima estimativa não mude da anterior (com base em uma precisão desejada).

É possível implementar esse método em Javascript com o seguinte código (note a escolha deliberada de precisão com 5 casas decimais na chamada de `.toFixed(5)`):

```
function bab_sqrt(fValue) {
    if(fValue < 0)
        return 0;

    var fNext = fValue.toString().length * 100; // "Chuta" o valor inicial da raíz com base no número de dígitos
    var fPrev = 0;

    // Processa enquanto não convergir
    // (isto é, enquanto fNext for diferente de fPrev com precisão de 5 decimais)
    do {
        fPrev = fNext;
        fNext = 0.5 * (fPrev + fValue / fPrev);
    } while(fNext.toFixed(5) != fPrev.toFixed(5))

    return fNext;
}
```

Mas note que ele não funciona (sempre devolve `0`) para números negativos/complexos (tal qual a implementação nativa, que retorna `NaN`).

Eis um exemplo mais completo, que compara os resultados nativos (implementado com `Math.sqrt` do navegador) e manual (implementado com a função acima).

```js
function doCalc() {
    var fValue = parseFloat(document.getElementById("value").value);
    
    var fRootNative = Math.sqrt(fValue);
    var fRootCalc = bab_sqrt(fValue);
    
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<p>Raíz (nativa) = " + fRootNative.toFixed(5) + "</p><p>Raíz (calculada) = " + fRootCalc.toFixed(5) + "</p>";
}

function bab_sqrt(fValue) {
    if(fValue < 0)
        return 0;

    var fNext = fValue.toString().length * 100; // "Chuta" o valor inicial da raíz com base no número de dígitos
    var fPrev = 0;

    // Processa enquanto não convergir
    // (isto é, enquanto fNext for diferente de fPrev com precisão de 5 decimais)
    do {
        fPrev = fNext;
        fNext = 0.5 * (fPrev + fValue / fPrev);
    } while(fNext.toFixed(5) != fPrev.toFixed(5))
    
    return fNext;
}
```

```html
Valor para extração da raíz: <input type="text" id="value"><br>
<button onclick="doCalc()">Calcular</button>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Muito boa reposta @Luiz Vieira, gostei da referência ao método de newton  ,  embora tenha achado a pergunta meio óbvia para o apontamento do Sergio, parabéns.

Comment: Obrigado, @WellingtonSilvaRibeiro. Eu só postei a resposta porque poderia ajudar o AP caso fosse um trabalho acadêmico. De fato, a resposta do Sergio (juntamente com o comentário do bfavaretto) é a que realmente responde à pergunta, no sentido de que a implementação fica a cargo do navegador. Essa informação, embora possa parecer trivial, pode vir a ser importante dependendo do uso de Javascript que alguém irá fazer (científico ou em jogos, por exemplo).

Comment: @Luiz Vieira, resposta perfeita. Ainda que eu não tenha sido perfeitamente claro, admito, na minha pergunta você captou a essência, cara.
Eu queria saber sim como o JS calculava, e nisso a resposta do amigo Sergio ajudou bastante, mas a sua respondeu a questão que veio a seguir na minha cabeça.
Eu sabia que era por estimação, mas não fazia idéia do cálculo. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Por nada. Ainda assim, vale lembrar que há muitos outros métodos. O [comentário do @bfavaretto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71974/como-funciona-o-math-sqrt-no-javascript/72014?noredirect=1#comment147529_71985), por exemplo, apresenta um código que (após uma verificação bem superficial) parece usar o método de cálculo digito-a-dígito. Tem uma descrição dele também [lá no link da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Digit-by-digit_calculation) que eu já mencionei. Provavelmente essa é a implementação utilizada pelos navegadores. :)

Comment: P.S.: O método de Newton é a próxima sugestão nos algoritmos da IEEE 754, na seção "*Other Methods*", item A.

Answer (score 8):

A [ECMAScript (ES6) diz](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-math.sqrt):

> #### Math.sqrt ( x )
>
> Returns an implementation-dependent approximation to the square root of x.
> If x is NaN, the result is NaN.
> If x is less than 0, the result is NaN.
> If x is +0, the result is +0.
> If x is −0, the result is −0.
> If x is +∞, the result is +∞.

Traduzindo a parte importante seria:

> Retorna uma aproximação da raiz quadrada de x **dependente/consoante da implementação.**

Ou seja cada Browser pode implementar de maneira diferente. Isso não ajuda muito à tua pergunta... mas pelo menos sabes que não é um valor normalizado ou com uma regra igual para todos os browsers (pelo menos não há essa obrigação).

Comment: O ECMAScript 5 diz a mesma coisa. E recomenda usar [os algoritmos da IEEE 754](http://www.netlib.org/cgi-bin/netlibfiles.txt?format=txt&filename=fdlibm%2Fe_sqrt.c), que por sua vez recomenda usar a implementação do hardware (processador), quando disponível.